# Magento cookie settings for subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain, session-cookies, magento-1.8

When I am installing Magento under a subdomain of my production domain, I cannot login to magento admin. For example, my domain name is example.com where I have installed magento and it is in production, I am ok with admin login.

However, I have a subdomain called test.example.com and I installed magento there for testing purpose. Now, if I try to login to the test site, I can't login. The username and passwords are correct. I see no error message. It just reloads the same login page. Same things happens when I try to login to my production site admin panel.

If I clear the cookies related to example.com and test.example.com and then try to login to the admin panel of example.com, I am fine. Now, when I try to login to test.example.com admin panel, the problem starts again.

[image: This is what my Session Cookie management settings]

Is there anybody who can help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your live system's cookie are set for `.example.com`, which means for your live system's domain and also **all** subdomains. Because `test.example.com` is a subdomain, both cookies are valid for it.

Try the following settings, then Magento will set cookies for `.www.example.com` and `.test.example.com` and your live domain's cookies will not interfere with your subdomain's.

[image: live domain]

[image: subdomain]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am testing using that already. I just did example.com instead of www.example.com as I read somewhere that I do not need www. However, your answer says I need www. I will update about my findings

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved the problem by putting the cookie domain value to www.example.com to production and test.example.com to my test site from Session Cookie management from the admin. Although this solution will not allow users to login without www i.e. example.com/admin will not work. We will have to use www.example.com/admin for successfully login to magento admin